# How to call a stored procedure with less parameters?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
String foo = "{call myStored(?,?,?,?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(foo);
callableStatement.setInt(1, 10);

callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I have a stored procedure with 20 parameters. Is it possible to only set a few of the parameters?
The stored procedure also returns a value. I've tried to just do `call myStored(?)` and set `callableStatement.setInt("colname", 10);` I get missmatch in the numbers of parameters... Should the return value also count as a parameter, so it's 21?

Answer (score 4):

You have to bind all parameters you declare in the statement. (for each ? you have to provide value with  set* or registerOutParameter) But if these parameters have default value (that is possible in PL/SQL) then you don't have to declare them in the statement.

In DB:

```
FUNCTION get_empName(emp_id NUMBER, emp_name VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'Something') RETURN VARCHAR2
```

In Java:

```
String statement1= "{? = call get_empName(?)}"; // valid statement
String statement2= "{? = call get_empName(?, ?)}"; // valid statement
```

If you have a stored function (it returns value) then you can write the statement like this

```
String foo = "{? = call myStored(?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(foo);    
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);
callableStatement.setInt(2, 10);

callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can I declare less parameters than the stored procedure? Let's say it takes 20 parameters, and if I bind only three "{? = call get_empName(?,?,?)};

Comment: Yes, you can declare less parameters then the stored procedure but these parameters must be optional. You have to provide all required parameters.